# ETS function in forecast package is not choosing minimized AICc

Tags: r, time-series, aic, exponential-smoothing

I have the following Time Series:

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 23 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 2.827639 3.025919 2.758508 2.615995 2.544861 2.581062 2.384300 2.295275
 [9] 2.295331 2.205670 2.079790 2.097358 2.256680 2.212057 2.309781 2.494873
[17] 2.784051 2.701699 2.742262 2.886574 2.943660 3.000333 3.023846
```

I am using ETS in two different ways to obtain a forecast model:

```
ModelSelection <- ets(df.data, model = "AAN", alpha = 0.5, beta = 0.499)
ModelSelection

ETS(A,A,N) 

Call:
 ets(y = df.data, model = "AAN", alpha = 0.5, beta = 0.499) 

  Smoothing parameters:
    alpha = 0.5 
    beta  = 0.499 

  Initial states:
    l = 3.0185 
    b = -0.0523 

  sigma:  0.1424

      AIC      AICc       BIC 
-15.95075 -14.68759 -12.54426 

OptSelection <- ets(df.data, model = "AAN")

OptSelection

ETS(A,A,N) 

Call:
 ets(y = df.data, model = "AAN") 

  Smoothing parameters:
    alpha = 0.4417 
    beta  = 0.392 

  Initial states:
    l = 3.0246 
    b = -0.0669 

  sigma:  0.1391

       AIC       AICc        BIC 
-13.008568  -9.479157  -7.331097
```

My understanding from reading through the literature is that, when not specifying any parameters, `ets()` will minimize AICc. The prediction intervals are better for the second model as it has a smaller sigma value. Is `ets()` choosing an optimized model by AICc alone?
Or is there more going into the selection process I am missing?

Here are the error statistics as well:

```
accuracy(ModelSelection)

           ME      RMSE        MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE      ACF1
  0.008646586 0.1293883 0.09940506 0.3967123 3.831806 0.9055805 -0.06642329

accuracy(OptSelection)

           ME      RMSE        MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE      ACF1
   0.01147291 0.1264468 0.09997687 0.5508859 3.876411 0.9107897 0.05564438
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the basis for your question is... are you by any chance comparing the AICc of the first model, which has no free parameters, with the AICc of the second, which has two free parameters?  Try calculating the AICc of the first model using the parameter estimates output by the second model to see why this might not be a good idea.

Comment: @jbowman Thank you. It was just a fundamental misunderstanding of the computation of AICc.

Comment: So then your problem has been solved? Or do you still have a question?